# Using c:import to load Spring MVC View into div

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am trying to embed one page in another using `<c:import>` and am having difficulties.

If I use `<c:import url="http://www.google.com" />` things work great.

I'm trying to load a local route:

`@RequestMapping(value="/modules/some_module/{customerId}/bill", method=RequestMethod.GET)`

using:

`<c:import url="/modules/some_module/SOME_CUSTOMER_ID/bill" />`

And am getting nothing.  I don't have any issues loading simple `jsp` files using relative paths.

I have a suspicion, you can't load routes using a relative paths?  In that case is there an easy way to retrieve and append the protocol/domain?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this if your actual requirement is to dynamically get the webapp context:

```
<c:import url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/modules/some_module/SOME_CUSTOMER_ID/bill" />
```